# Fancy CV template wanted

Tags: templates, cv

I am looking for a CV template to reproduce (more or less) the following style:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want this? ;-)

Comment: De gustibus non est disputandum. ;-)

Comment: Errare (!!!!) humanum est :-P

Comment: I wouldn't use LaTeX here, to be honest.

Comment: Quidquid Latine dictum sit altum videtur, I suppose.

Comment: A friend of mine built a CV similar, I made some updated to work in French an I have add a cover letter. 
The source code is [here](https://github.com/davebulaval/CV_template) .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it turns out, [LaTeXtemplates](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/twenty-seconds-resumecv) has a template that resembles what you want.

[Link to the github repository](https://github.com/spagnuolocarmine/TwentySecondsCurriculumVitae-LaTex)

[image: twentySeconddsPreview]